# How to write an Object to a JSON file in Java?

Tags: java, json, object, gson, filewriter

I am creating a program whereby I need to save(write) objects to a JSON, and then load(read) these objects back into the program. I have told that GSON is a good way to do this. However, I am having some troubles with it. I have tried the following:

```
Gson g = new Gson();
try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file)) {
    String j = g.toJson(board);
    writer.write(j);  
    writer.flush();  
    writer.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

When I run the program, I get the error:

> class object3 declares multiple JSON fields named state

The object I am trying to write to the JSON has an ID, and an Array of another Object (`object2`), and each of these objects have an Array of another Object (`object3`). `object3` has multiple fields, mostly strings. What is the simplest way for me to write an object such as this to a JSON file and then be able to read it back into my program?

Comment: Did you check some tutorials, like [this](https://www.baeldung.com/gson-save-file)? You might want to add your objects as well (as code sample).

Comment: Could you share your JSON also. It looks like JSON itself is invalid, having multiple keys with the same name.

Comment: What do you mean share my JSON?

Comment: Can you show us your object3 class ?

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to serialize and deserialize object state in a JSON format, and don't care too much about the exact shape of the JSON, [XStream](https://x-stream.github.io/json-tutorial.html) makes this very easy. It tolerates almost any Java object structure and isn't as pernickety as Gson.

It was originally designed to serialize to XML, but if you use the `JettisonMappedXmlDriver` it will output JSON instead. I have found it to be a well-written and reliable library.

```
Product product = new Product("Banana", "123", 23.00);
XStream xstream = new XStream(new JettisonMappedXmlDriver());
xstream.setMode(XStream.NO_REFERENCES);
xstream.alias("product", Product.class);

System.out.println(xstream.toXML(product));
```

Produces:

> {"product":{"name":"Banana","id":123,"price":23.0}}

To read it back in:

```
XStream xstream = new XStream(new JettisonMappedXmlDriver());
xstream.alias("product", Product.class);
Product product = (Product) xstream.fromXML(json);
System.out.println(product.getName());
```

Prints:

> Banana